# Change style of all occurrences of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stylesheet, markup

I want my site title to display in a unique font from the rest of the content every time it appears in a heading, for branding reasons. For simplicity, let's pretend my special font is Courier and my company is called SparklePony. So, a line like,

```
<h1 class="title">SparklePony Board of Directors</h1>
```

would show a headline with the word SparklePony in Courier and Board of Directors in my site default font, Arial. (Yes, I know this would be hideous.)

I've tried using a jQuery string replacement, but I don't want to *replace* the string, I just want to see it in Courier (adding a class to just that word, or something of the like.) Replacing `SparklePony` with `<span class="sparkle-pony">SparklePony</span>` caused the whole ugly string with tags and everything to show on my site, rather than adding the class.

Am I doing something wrong with my string replace, or is there a better way to style all occurrences of a string?

Comment: What is the code that you used to do the replace? Did you replace the innerHTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this - specifying the selector you want - #('h1') or by class.

```
$('.title').html(function(i,v){    
   return v.replace(/SparklePony/g,'<span class="sparkle">SparklePony</span>');
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cQjsu/

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the code (which would be kinda important in questions like this), best guess is that you're using `.text()` instead of `.html()` which would parse the HTML correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It could do with some tidying, but this may be a good starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/c24w/Fznh4/9/.

HTML

```
<div id="title">Highlight this blah blah HiGhLiGhT THIS blah</div>
<button id="clickme">Click to highlight text</button>
```

CSS

```
#title{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
span.highlight{
  color: #09f;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function highlightText(element, phrase, allOccurrences, caseSensitive){
  var modifiers = (allOccurrences ? 'g' : '') + (caseSensitive ? '' : 'i');
  var text = element.innerHTML;
  element.innerHTML = text.replace(new RegExp(phrase, modifiers), function(match){
    return '<span class="highlight">' + match + '</span>';
  });
}

var button = document.getElementById('clickme');
var el = document.getElementById('title');

button.onclick = function(){
  highlightText(el, 'highlight this', true, false);
  button.onclick = null;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like that :

```
$.each($(".title"),function({
$(this).html($(this).html().replace("SparklePony","<span class='sparkle-pony'>SparklePony</span>"))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice and short:

```
var $body = $("body");
$body.html($body.html().replace(/SparklePony/ig, "<span class='cool'>SparklePony</span>"));​
```

But keep in mind that `$("body")` is a very costly selector. You should consider a more precise parent target.

[Demo here (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/59PrJ/1/)

Comment: I am limiting it to h1's for now. Point taken.